# Automate accounting entries in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to automate a process in VBA for an accounting service.

Each month, I received a file which contains different societies with their revenue (total amount, amount without tax and Vat). Each society has different stores which are located in different places.

**Input example:**
[image]

Example : society Naf Naf has 2 stores (001 and 002):

- Store 001 sold 3 products: 1,94 + 18,25 + 83,95
- Store 002 sold 2 products: 6,74 + 3,56

**Output example:** For the output, I have to bring out the amounts for each store by following this model:
[image]

Some values don't change :

Column F: "EUR"

Line about the VAT (here example line 3):

- Column E : 45200100
- Column I : "VAT"
- Column J : "T"
- Column K : "VO"
- Column L : "SVSE"
- Column M : "N20"
- Column N : "20"

Example with Naf Naf society: Naf Naf has 2 stores (001 and 002).

- Line 2, column G: Amount ex-tax sum (input: column E) of all the 001 stores
- Line 4, column G: VAT sum of ALL the Naf Naf stores (input: column F)
- Line 4, column O: Amount ex-tax sum of ALL the stores.
- Line 5, column H: Amount ex-tax + VAT (G2+G3+G4 or G4+O4)

There are many stores for each society that why I would like to automate this process.

Do you have any clue how I can proceed?

**Code:**
I did for Naf Naf Society which has 2 stores (3 lines with 001 ID and 2 with 002 ID):

Society NAF NAF, store 001 :

```
Sub Naf001()
 
Dim Naf As Range
Dim SUM_NAF As Double
Dim LastRow As Double

LastRow = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last row
Set Naf = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion  'setting whole range of data
Sheets("Feuil1").AutoFilterMode = False 'turning off all filters
Naf.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="001" 'filtering data - this data will change
SUM_NAF = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Feuil1").Range("D1:D" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) 'summing filtered data
 
Sheets("Feuil2").Select
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("A" & LastRow).Value = "Naf Naf"
Range("C" & LastRow).Value = "001" ' this data will change
Range("D" & LastRow).Value = "03700"
Range("E" & LastRow).Value = "59800019FR"
Range("F" & LastRow).Value = "EUR"
Range("G" & LastRow).Value = SUM_NAF
Range("I" & LastRow).Value = "AQ SOLDE" 
End Sub
```

Society NAF NAF, store 002 :

```
Sub Naf002()
     
    Dim Naf As Range
    Dim SUM_NAF As Double
    Dim LastRow As Double
    
    LastRow = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last row
    Set Naf = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion  'setting whole range of data
    Sheets("Feuil1").AutoFilterMode = False 'turning off all filters
    Naf.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="002" 'filtering data by store - this data will change
    SUM_NAF = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Feuil1").Range("D1:D" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) 'summing filtered data
     
    Sheets("Feuil2").Select
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("A" & LastRow).Value = "Naf Naf"
    Range("C" & LastRow).Value = "002" ' this data will change
    Range("D" & LastRow).Value = "03700"
    Range("E" & LastRow).Value = "59800019FR"
    Range("F" & LastRow).Value = "EUR"
    Range("G" & LastRow).Value = SUM_NAF
    Range("I" & LastRow).Value = "AQ SOLDE"
End Sub
```

Society NAF NAF, VAT :

```
Sub Naf_Vat()
   
    Dim Naf_Vat As Range
    Dim SUM_Naf_Vat As Double
    Dim LastRow As Double
    
    LastRow = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set Naf_Vat = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Sheets("Feuil1").AutoFilterMode = False
    Naf_Vat.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Naf Naf" 'filtering data by Society
    SUM_Naf_Vat = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Feuil1").Range("E1:E" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("A" & LastRow).Value = "Naf Naf"
    Range("C" & LastRow).Value = "VAT"
    Range("E" & LastRow).Value = "45200100"
    Range("F" & LastRow).Value = "EUR"
    Range("G" & LastRow).Value = SUM_Naf_Vat
    Range("I" & LastRow).Value = "VAT 20%"
    Range("K" & LastRow).Value = "T"
    Range("L" & LastRow).Value = "VO"
    Range("M" & LastRow).Value = "SVSE"
    Range("N" & LastRow).Value = "N20"
    Range("O" & LastRow).Value = "20.00"
    Range("P" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C[-9]+R[-1]C[-9]"
    Range("Q" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share a dummy workbook in order to test it? It takes time to build something only looking to your pictures... I would like to supply a solution and I will also like to test it.

Comment: Should all societies have two stores? If not, should the code insert rows in the "Output" sheet and fill them with all found stores? If so, this means that you rule of filling row 4 should be dynamic, which complicates a lot all processing. I am afraid that your question is not clear enough in order for somebody to start preparing an answer.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru, I'm sorry for my English.. Is it possible in stackoverlflow to share a workbook ?

Comment: The best way is to clearly explain what is to be done and paste editable files. If you cannot do that, please send it to my personal mail account (in my profile), or use a transfer site. For instance, the [next one](https://easyupload.io/) is free and easy to be used...

Comment: But please, try clarifying the issue I put in discussion above...

Comment: I edit my question. Thank you a lot, I will send you an e-mail

Comment: Societies can have more than 2 stores. So, yes… in the “output”, it must be filled by all the found stores. In the file I received each month there are between 15-20 societies and around 300 stores

Comment: You said that **Columns D, E, F, I, J, K, L, M, N won’t change**. Then, you also say about some lines (2, 4, 5) to be filled. Now, based on what to be chosen the appropriate lines to be filed in case of more than two store places? And I replied to your mail telling that the workbook is not eloquent enough, explaining why...

Comment: I can observe that in column `D:D", which should remain unchanged, there are data (03700, 03700 -two times) for the first society and the same for the second one. Should I understand that in case of a society having 3 stores, D:D column will be filled with three such Departments? Then, are there all the time an empty row between each society data? Since the societies are not in alphabetical order, the code must extract the order somehow... I cannot start anything without understanding what you have and  what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It will work on a workbook (as you sent) containing data starting from column A:A in both involved sheets. The Output sheet **must have each society data separated from the others by an empty row**. Each society must have in column D:D (DPT) so many codes as stores exist for it. I mean, for a society having two stores, `03700` (or something else) should exist twice, as in your example. But for another one having three stores, another row must be inserted, in a way to have one extra 'society name' above the first 'society name10'. Four such names instead of two. The code uses arrays and dictionaries and should be very fast. I commented it in a way to make its algorithm easy to be understood:

```
Sub AutomateAccouontingEntries()
 Dim shInp As Worksheet, lastR1 As Long, shOut As Worksheet, lastR2 As Long, rngSoc As Range
 Dim dictS As Object, A As Range, cel As Range, i As Long, j As Long
 Dim dictSt As Object, arr, arrOut, arrItem, El, ElIt, arrIt, arrDict, noRows As Long
 
 Set shInp = Worksheets("Feuil1")
 Set shOut = Worksheets("Feuil2")
 'check if the active workbook is the appropriate one:
  If shInp.Range("A1") <> "Society" Or shOut.Range("A1") <> "Society" Then _
       MsgBox "The active workbook is not appropriate!" & vbCrLf & _
                  "It must contain the header ""Society"" in ""AA1"" for both used sheets...": Exit Sub
                  
  lastR1 = shInp.Range("A" & shInp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   'last row in input sheet
  lastR2 = shOut.Range("A" & shOut.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'last row in output sheet
  arr = shInp.Range("A2:E" & lastR1).Value          'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  arrOut = shOut.Range("A2:O" & lastR2).Value       'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  
  Set dictS = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")   'set the dictionary keeping unique societies
  Set dictSt = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  'set the dictionary keeping society|store
  
  'load the dictionary with unique societies:
  Set rngSoc = shOut.Range("A2:A" & lastR2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
  dictS(shOut.Range("A2").Value) = Array(2, 0, 0, 0) 'place the first row of the first society (second row)
  For Each A In rngSoc.Areas
        'a unique key as the cell down the empty row value and 3 zero values to be used
        'for keeping: number of stores existing occurrences, summarized VAT and summarized ex-tax
        dictS(A.Cells(1).Offset(1).Value) = Array(A.Cells(1).Offset(1).Row, 0, 0, 0)
  Next A
  
  'load dictionary with concatenation between unique societies and their store, then fill data:
  For Each El In dictS.Keys       'iterate between the previous created dictionaries keys:
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)      'iterate between the first sheet arr rows:
        If arr(i, 1) = El Then    'if array element in first column is equal with the dictionary keys:
            If Not dictSt.Exists(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) Then   'if the concatenated dictionary key does not exist:
                dictSt(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) = Array(arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4), arr(i, 5))    'create the key and fill it with data
                arrIt = dictS(arr(i, 1)): arrIt(1) = arrIt(1) + 1: dictS(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt 'fill the number of occurrences
            Else                          'for the next occurrences update the values by summing them:
                arrItem = dictSt(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2))
                  arrItem(0) = arrItem(0) + arr(i, 3)
                  arrItem(1) = arrItem(1) + arr(i, 4)
                  arrItem(2) = arrItem(2) + arr(i, 5)
                dictSt(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) = arrItem
            End If
        End If
    Next i
 Next El
 ReDim arrDict(dictSt.Count - 1) 'ReDim the array keeping the already processed dictionaries
 Dim k As Long, mtch
 
 'fill the final array (arrOut) with the values extracted from dictionaries:
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrOut)               'iterate between the array rows:
    For j = 0 To dictSt.Count - 1          'iterate between the dictionaries (concatenated keys) elements:
        If arrOut(i, 1) = Split(dictSt.Keys()(j), "|")(0) And dictS.Exists(arrOut(i, 1)) Then 'if in A:A is a string equal to left
                                                                                                                   'concatenated dictionary key:
            mtch = Application.Match(dictSt.Keys()(j), arrDict, 0) 'check if the dictionary key exists in the array of processed dicts
            If IsError(mtch) Then                                  'if the dictionary concatenated key has not been used, yet:
                If dictS(arrOut(i, 1))(1) > 0 Then                 'if still not used stores exists:
                    arrOut(dictS(arrOut(i, 1))(0) - 1, 3) = Split(dictSt.Keys()(j), "|")(1) 'place the Store in C:C
                    arrOut(dictS(arrOut(i, 1))(0) - 1, 7) = dictSt.items()(j)(1)     'place ex-tax sum, per store, in G:G
                    arrItem = dictS(arrOut(i, 1)): arrItem(0) = arrItem(0) + 1 'increment the row where next time to place the store
                    arrItem(1) = arrItem(1) - 1                            'decrease the number of existing occurrences
                    arrItem(2) = arrItem(2) + dictSt.items()(j)(2)         'sumarize the VAT per society, all stores
                    arrItem(3) = arrItem(3) + dictSt.items()(j)(1)         'sumarize ex-tax per society, all stores
                    dictS(arrOut(i, 1)) = arrItem                          'place the updated array back in dictionary
                    'after the last store has been used, place also the total VAT and ex-tax amounts, per society:
                    If dictS(arrOut(i, 1))(1) = 0 Then
                        arrOut(dictS(arrOut(i, 1))(0) - 1, 7) = dictS(arrOut(i, 1))(2)    'place total VAT per society, in G:G
                        arrOut(dictS(arrOut(i, 1))(0) - 1, 15) = dictS(arrOut(i, 1))(3)  'place total ex-tax per society, in O:O
                        arrOut(dictS(arrOut(i, 1))(0), 8) = dictS(arrOut(i, 1))(2) + dictS(arrOut(i, 1))(3) 'ex-tax + VAT in H:H
                    End If
                    arrDict(k) = dictSt.Keys()(j): k = k + 1    'place the processed dict keys in the arrDict array
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
 Next i
 'drop the final array content, at once:
 shOut.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrOut), UBound(arrOut, 2)).Value = arrOut
 MsgBox "Ready...", vbInformation, "Job done"
End Sub
```

If something not clear, please do not hesitate to ask for clarification.

In order to preliminary identify the number of stores per each society, you can use the next function:

```
Function NumberOfStores(sh As Worksheet) As String
   Dim dict As Object, arr, arrIt, lastR As Long, i As Long, mtch, strTxt As String
   
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastR).Value
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(arr(i, 2))
        Else
            mtch = Application.Match(arr(i, 2), dict(arr(i, 1)), 0)
            If IsError(mtch) Then
                arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1)): ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1)
                arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = arr(i, 2)
                dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt
            End If
        End If
   Next i
   'Prepare the output
   For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
        strTxt = strTxt & dict.Keys()(i) & ": " & UBound(dict.items()(i)) + 1 & vbCrLf
   Next
   NumberOfStores = strTxt
End Function
```

It will display the society name and its number of stores in `Immediate Window`. You can see this window by pressing `Ctrl + G', being in VBE.

The function can be simple called in this way:

```
Sub testNumberOfStoresPerSociety()
   Debug.Print NumberOfStores(Worksheets("Feuil1"))
   MsgBox "Please, open Visual Basic for Application Editor (Ctrl + F11) and press Ctrl + G to see the number of stores for each society", _
              vbInformation, "Prepare each society for a specific number of stores"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @FaneDury, thanks for all your work ! That's extacly what I was looking for. It works with my "real' data I use at work :)

Comment: @Larow Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, vote up the answer and more important, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the code works...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to do that ! Thank you again